# Force definition of template class member function?

Tags: c++, templates, instantiation, member, definition

I have a template class as follows:

```
template <class T, int N>
class kernel: public std::array<T, N << 1> {
    :
public:
    kernel(void) : std::array<T, N << 1>{} { blah... }
    template <typename... E>
    kernel(const E &&... e):
        std::array<T, N << 1>{{std::forward<const E>(e)...}} { blah... }
    :
    T write_wav(const char *filename) const { blah... }
};
```

In my program, I instantiate `kernel<T, N>` for various values of T and N without problems, but never actually call `kernel<T, N>::write_wav()`, and so the compiler does not generate a definition for it.

Thing is, I WANT the compiler to generate a definition, because I want to call `kernel<T, N>::write_wav()` from my debugger (Immediate Window in VC++2015).  How would I force the compiler to do so?

Thus far, the only working approach I stumbled upon is to call `kernel<T, N>::write_wav()` from the constructor, and hence generate a reference to it:

```
kernel(void) : std::array<T, N << 1>{} { write_wav(nullptr); }
template <typename... E>
kernel(const E &&... e):
    std::array<T, N << 1>{{std::forward<const E>(e)...}} { write_wav(nullptr); }
```

Alas, this introduces an unnecessary execution overhead.  Is there a cleaner way to do this?

If I try taking the address of kernel::write_wav(), like so:

```
    kernel(void) : std::array<T, N << 1>{} { &kernel<T, N>::write_wav; }
```

Then things compile fine but the member function is still not instantiated (probably because the compiler can figure out that its address has no uses).

Alternately, I tried creating a pointer to member inside the class and assigning the address to it:

```
    T(kernel<T, N>::*write_wav_ptr)(const char *filename) const;
    kernel(void) : std::array<T, N << 1>{} { write_wav_ptr = &kernel<T, N>::write_wav; }
```

Then things work fine (and kernel::write_wav() gets instantiated), but each instance of kernel now has an extra data member that I don't really need.

Comment: Is `write_wave` the same thing you refer to as `output_wave`? The compiler should generate a definition for it for any given `kernel<T, N>` which has been instantiated.

Comment: Take the address of it

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback.  I've updated my state of knowledge in the description above. The take-away is that assigning the address of the member function to a data member does the trick -- at the expense of making each instance of the class slightly bigger -- so this is still not ideal.